# Ubuntu Web Server Processor?

Tags: server, webserver

I am thinking of building a home based web server built on Ubuntu and am curious as to if the following processor will be able to handle Ubuntu server.

Intel Dual-core Celeron 1037U (1.8GHz) (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128679)

I am also going to have:

4 GB of DDR3 RAM and
1TB HDD 7200 RPM

What do you guys think? I want to set up a LAMP environment, I feel like this will help me learn Linux and be able to host my own personal web server.

Thank you!

Comment: Try with this tutorial: [Ubuntu Web Server from scratch, free web hosting (LAMP, FTP, Webmin, PHPMyAdmin, SSH)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKJ55ebMcOc)

Comment: This should be a dup of the "what are the minimum requirements for different versions of ubuntu" question, but I can't seem to find it in the search. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work to get a LAMP stack up and running, I've added a couple free alternatives that might help you get your feet wet.

AWS has a free tier, you get a micro instance on ec2, a small on RDS and a loadbalancer, good for toying around.

Also, depending on the specs of your current system could play around with Linux using Virtualbox or Vmware Player.

Another good tool for users with a Windows background that would like to start down a more Unixy path is [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), hich will get you a bash shell and access to some GNU packages